# When Scroll UITableView it overlap the name iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uicollectionview, alassetslibrary, alasset

When i scroll the tableview gives this type of overlapping [image]

I write the below code in CellForRow AtIndexPath method,I create tableview programatically...

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}

NSDictionary *info = [ASSETHELPER getGroupInfo:_groupArray[indexPath.row]];
UIImageView *view;

if (indexPath.row % 2) {
    view=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dark_bg"]];
}else{
    view=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"light_bg"]];
}
cell.backgroundView=view;

UIImageView *imgView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 50)];
imgView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
[imgView.layer setCornerRadius:25];
[imgView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[imgView.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
[imgView setImage:[info objectForKey:@"thumbnail"]];
[cell.contentView addSubview:imgView];

UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 20, 200, 30)];

[label setText:[info objectForKey:@"name"]];
[cell.contentView addSubview:label];

return cell;
```

}

Comment: We are not wizards or psychics. Add some code, and more details.

Comment: You have not handled cell re-useability properly. post your cellPathForRowAtIndexPath code here.

Comment: Much better. Sorry if I sounded rude before. The problem here is `[cell.contentView addSubview:label];`. Every time `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called, you are adding a new label each time. Since cells are being reused, the label added before is never removed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this code .You have used dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %d",indexPath.row];

UITableViewCell *cell=[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

if (cell == nil)
{
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

Comment: Check it and let you know.Check my profile you will get my mail id.

Comment: please help me for to save video into custom album

Answer (score -1):

```
You can try with it. Just remove the previous contentView after create a table cell.

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell==nil)
    {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    //****add this code*******//
    for (UIImageView *v in [cell.contentView subviews])
    {
        [v removeFromSuperview];
        NSLog(@"%@ hello \n\n\n\n\n%@",v,[cell.contentView  subviews]);
    }
    for (UILabel *v in [cell.contentView subviews])
    {
        [v removeFromSuperview];
        NSLog(@"%@ hello \n\n\n\n\n%@",v,[cell.contentView  subviews]);
    }/////////
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    NSDictionary *info = [ASSETHELPER getGroupInfo:_groupArray[indexPath.row]];
    UIImageView *view;
    if (indexPath.row % 2)
    {
        view=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dark_bg"]];
    }
    else
    {
        view=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"light_bg"]];
    }
    cell.backgroundView=view;
    UIImageView *imgView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 50)];
    imgView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [imgView.layer setCornerRadius:25];
    [imgView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [imgView.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
    [imgView setImage:[info objectForKey:@"thumbnail"]];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imgView];

    UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 20, 200, 30)];

    [label setText:[info objectForKey:@"name"]];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Just add this code after creating cell. I think it will be help you.                                                                  for (UIImageView *v in [cell.contentView subviews]) {
        [v removeFromSuperview];
    NSLog(@"%@ hello \n\n\n\n\n%@",v,[cell.contentView  subviews]);
        }                                                                   for (UILabel *v in [cell.contentView subviews]) {
        [v removeFromSuperview];
    NSLog(@"%@ hello \n\n\n\n\n%@",v,[cell.contentView  subviews]);
}

Comment: You know it's not rocket science to format your code correctly. I've done it for near enough every other answer you have given but now I am just going to downvote. I will remove once you have formatted your answer correctly so it is readable -1